# using date two ways producing different results

Tags: mysql, date

I'm getting two drastically different results when I run these two queries and I was hoping someone could tell me why....I can see the slight differences in syntax but I'm not sure which is giving me the value I'm looking for which is "give me all records from forms from this month and year that I'm running this on.

```
select *
from forms
where month(date) = month(now()) and year(date) = year(now());  

select *
from forms
where Month(date) = MONTH(now()) AND YEAR(now());
```

Right now...the top is returning 270 rows and the bottom query 186.

Thanks

Comment: Are you sure the bottom query returns less number of rows?

Comment: I don't get the bottom query `AND YEAR(now())`? What does that even mean? If you switched the result counts your cause is that you check for month = month and year = year in the upper query and just month = month in the lower query

Comment: Right. The bottom query is a typo, but the result is odd. It's not erroring....just giving me a different result back. less rows, by about 100....

Comment: `AND YEAR(now())` from second is like `AND 1` and can be omitted. So, it's more wide query and should return more rows than first.

Comment: @vp_arth Yes the bottom should return the same or more.